# Can't resolve babel loader in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

After `npm install` of `react-facebook-login` I get an error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-with-button.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\ichen\Developer\plain\Strapi.POC\client\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js' in 'C:\Users\ichen\Developer\plain\Strapi.POC\client'
```

I think its because the package specifies in its package.json, under devDependencies `"babel-loader":  "^6.2.4"` and React is using babel-loader > 7
I'm not really sure though. What should I do? I don't want to eject the React App to downgrade the babel version...

Comment: Hi Octavia, can you share your dependencies list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I changed the babel-loader in the package.json of the dependency from 6.2.4 to 8.0 (the one used by React currently), saved the file, re-ran npm start, and everything compiled.